# Mongo db: transform a field in a .map .join fashion

Tags: mongodb, projection

Here is a sample collection:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  users: [
   {name: 'John Doe'}, {name: 'Ruth Paulson'}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  users: [
   {name: 'Meg Alosaurus'}, {name: 'Ruth Paulson'}
  ]
 }

]
```

How do I write a query to get such results:

```
[
  { id: 1, usernames: ['John Doe', 'Ruth Paulson'] }
  { id: 2, usernames: ['Meg Alosaurus', 'Ruth Paulson'] }
]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
[
  { id: 1, usernames: 'John Doe, Ruth Paulson'},
  { id: 2, usernames: 'Meg Alosaurus, Ruth Paulson'}
]
```

In javascript, I would do:

```
collection.map(record => ({
  id: record.id,
  usernames: record.map(user => user.name)/*.join(', ')*/
}));
```

(Note: I'm very new to mongo db. I've tried some constructs like $project, mapReduce, $concat but couldn't get the result I wanted out of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query using aggregate.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: { path : "$users", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true }},
    {$group : {_id: "$_id", usernames : {$push : "$users.name"}}}
]);
```

**Output:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "usernames" : [ 
        "Meg Alosaurus", 
        "Ruth Paulson"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "usernames" : [ 
        "John Doe", 
        "Ruth Paulson"
    ]
}
```